# Adsense not showing after angular SSR conversion

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, server-side-rendering, adsense

I converted my website code developed in Angular from CSR to SSR to improve SEO, but noticed that adsense was not showing on the website yet, even though I placed ads.txt under dist /projectName/browser/ads.txt and I added this code in angular.json file :

```
      "assets": [
      "src/robots.txt",
      "src/ads.txt",
      "src/sitemap.xml",
      "src/assets"
      ],
```

Do you have an idea ? Do I have something technical to do? Should I resubmit adsense again or should I wait a bit before?

Thanks.

Comment: have you found a solution for that, ads tells that ads.txt not found

Comment: yes it works for me, you have to place ads.txt in index folder levem, and for me i had to resubmit adsense again, moreover i used ng2-adsense to place blocs in html